# Export a taproot multisig wallet

Tags: multi-signature, taproot, output-script-descriptors, private-key-export, miniscript

I have created a wallet, added a descriptors to make it multisig with `tr(KI, multi_a(2,pub1,pub2,pub3)` command.

Now, I want to import this to some UI but since the wallet doesn't have a private key I am unable to export the same.

Can anyone help how that can be done?

Comment: What wallet software are you trying to import to?

Comment: Unisat or OKK wallet

Comment: Are you sure they support miniscript descriptors?